# How to recognize a configuration file's syntax and its equivalent Markdown language identifier?

Tags: syntax, markdown, syntax-highlighting, configuration-files

#### Introduction

When configuring software packages, you encounter a variety of configuration files with a variety of different syntaxes used.

In addition to `.json`, `.xml`, `.yml` and `.properties`, below are a few examples of common syntaxes I am unable to find the name for.

#### White-space separation

```
# comment
value11 value12
value21 value22 value23 value24
```

You may find this syntax in "/etc/hosts" and also embedded under Apache2 configuration tags (e.g. `<VirtualHost>`), among other places. Seems to be used often for listing aliases.

#### White-space separation and nesting by indentation

```
Key1 value1 value2 value3
    Key2 value4 value5
    Key3 value6

Key4 value7
    Key5 value8
```

You may find this syntax in "~/.ssh/config". Nesting ties nested values to the parent values. Looks like yaml without symbols.

#### Apache2 config

You may have values separated by whitespace, and also XML-tags to separate blocks of configuration.

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Dovecot config

You start a block with specific keywords and curly braces, then you use `=` assignment like in `.properties` files.

```
protocol imap {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/imap.pem
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/imap.pem
}
protocol pop3 {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/pop3.pem
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/pop3.pem
}
```

#### Question

Although many software packages have their own configuration syntaxes, these syntaxes often have many similarities. It seems to me `.config`, `.conf` or `.cf` doesn't really say much about the syntax used.

My question is: **Do the above code-block syntaxes have names, and if they do, which language identifiers could be used for markdown code-blocks to apply proper syntax highlighting?**

For more sophisticated and custom configuration syntaxes, I am simply looking for a base-syntax language identifier which could apply most of the highlighting to the code-block.

````
```which-language-identifier-goes-here?
# comment
127.0.0.1 localhost example.com
```
````

````
```or-here?
# comment
Host remote-server
    HostName example.com
    User johndoe
```
````

Comment: Side note: the nesting you show in your `.ssh/config` example isn't doing anything. Entries in that file are grouped by `Host` (or `Match`), not by indentation. See `man ssh_config`.

Comment: Apache and Dovecot are their own proprietary formats. I'd try `apache` or `apache2` for the former, and I'd be surprised if the latter is supported anywhere. But that raises an important issue: which Markdown processor are you using? More importantly, which _syntax highlighting library?_ Your entire question depends on that. Look through that library's documentation to see what it supports.

Comment: @Chris A few editors which I use, that support markdown visualization: IntelliJ IDEA, Atom, Stackoverflow. I am not sure if I can answer your question about each one. Let's say this question is meant for stackoverflow, to narrow it down, and give an example of how we would handle a specific scenario. Even if you list all the available syntaxes that a certain tool supports, the question still remains: How do I know the specific *name* of some common configuration syntax, so that I can find it in the list and use the appropriate language identifier?

Answer (score 10):

[This link](https://support.codebasehq.com/articles/tips-tricks/syntax-highlighting-in-markdown) has a helpful list of available supported languages (note that your markdown editor also needs to support each language, for coloring/syntax).

For example, you should be able to use `apacheconf` for Apache conf (eg/ .htaccess, apache.conf', apache2.conf).

For example:

````
```apacheconf
# Change the PHP version of this directory
<FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php74___lsphp
</FilesMatch>
````

Comment: This is a good example list of supported languages. However, if you can name some, which one of these are common configuration file languages/syntax? One problem when trying to find the correct language identifier is knowing which ones are supported by the tool, but another problem is also **knowing the name of the syntax or language that you want highlighting for**. So far, using the identifiers "configuration", "conf" or "cfg" hasn't got me very far.

Comment: specifically for ssh config, the markdown syntax ssh-config (not listed in the above link) worked for me.

Comment: I think [this FAQ](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported-languages.html) from highlight.js would be a better resource to link to. It's what many websites use to do syntax highlighting (including StackOverflow), and stays up-to-date as the library gets updated.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for an answer to this question with regard to my `.gitconfig` file.

I think `ini` is a good default. So it would be:

````
```ini
[git]
    config = stuff
    goes   = here
    # ...
```
````

I think the `ini` would apply to other types of "conf" files as well, but I have no source for reference other than it works in this case. And it's listed in the link above.